# MFC button onclick handler

Tags: c++, events, mfc

I've 2 mfc buttons that I want to hide when a 3D stl file is being loaded and then show the buttons again when the stl loading is complete. This is to prevent user from re-loading the model when the loading is currently taking place.

The snippet of the code is as below

```
        { // change control state when model loads
            ((CButton *)this->GetDlgItem(IDC_RELOAD_STOCK_BUTTON))->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
            ((CButton *)this->GetDlgItem(IDOK))->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
            UpdateWindow();
        }

        // this process takes few seconds to load the file in the memory
        customStockModel.LoadFile(pathName.GetBuffer(pathName.GetLength()));

        {
            // change control state when the model has loaded
            ((CButton *)this->GetDlgItem(IDC_RELOAD_STOCK_BUTTON))->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
            ((CButton *)this->GetDlgItem(IDOK))->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
            UpdateWindow();

        }
```

The buttons do get hidden and reappear as I expect, but when I click the button area while it's hidden, the onclick handler gets called immediately when the button control reappears on the screen. it seems like the click message is queued and mfc calls the handler once the buttons are activated. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use EnableWindow instead of ShowWindow

Comment: While your message handler is being executed, your message loop doesn't run, and no input is processed. Processing continues, when your message handler returns (i.e. after the file has loaded). The described behavior is to be expected. If you want your GUI to handle input while the file load is in flight, you'll have to offload the loading procedure to another thread.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: you don't need to cast to `CButton*` you can write `this->GetDlgItem(IDC_RELOAD_STOCK_BUTTON))->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)`.

Comment: Instead of hiding the button, you disable the button by using EnableWindow as below:
GetDlgItem(IDC_RELOAD_STOCK_BUTTON)->EnableWindow(false)

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP I had EnableWindow in the beginning but that too has the same behaviour , the handler was being called once the buttons switched state from disabled to enabled, so tried hiding the controls.

Comment: That's what you get when you try to use MFC without knowing the Windows API. You **really** need to wrap your head around Windows' event based architecture. If you don't know when messages are dispatched, you stand zero chance of ever writing correct code.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should read your file in a thread - this would allow your application to refresh itself normally and process messages.
Now if you are unsure about this (multi-threading **is** hard), you can call regularly the following function in your lenghty function to clear up the message loops.

```
BOOL YourClass::DoEvents()
{
    MSG msg;
    while (::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        if (!AfxGetApp()->PreTranslateMessage(&msg))
        {
            ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
            ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

It will work but "proper programmers" will scream when they see this!
Good luck